# Manipulando um dataTable JSF + PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, gridview, datatable

Como faço para o `dataTable` só ser exibido depois que eu clicar em responder Simulado? Ao carregar a página, o `dataTable` logo de primeira já é exibido, mesmo não tenho nenhuma pergunta nele.

Eu tenho um `Command Button`:

```
<p:column headerText="Responder Simulado" style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
                        <p:commandButton id="responderSimulado" icon="ui-icon-check" title="Responder Simulado" update="@this :frmCadastroSimulado:exibePerguntas"
                            actionListener="#{responderSimuladoBean.recuperaSimuladoDeAcordoComCicloSelecionado}">
                            <f:param name="ciclo" value="#{ciclo.codigo}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

E logo em seguida, tenho um dataTable, que atualiza  logo depois que eu clico em responder.

```
<p:dataTable id="exibePerguntas" var="resposta" paginator="true"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="2,3,5,10,12" paginatorPosition="bottom"  
                value="#{responderSimuladoBean.respostas}"> 
                <p:column headerText="Perguntas">
                    <br></br>
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{resposta.questao.pergunta}"  />

                    <p:selectOneRadio id="resposta" style="width:35%"
                    value="#{resposta.respostaUsuario}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="A" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="B" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="C" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="D" itemValue="D" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="E" itemValue="E" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>

                    <h:outputText value="#{resposta.resultado}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como faço para o dataTable só ser exibido depois que eu clicar em responder Simulado?

Uma das formas é utilizar o atributo `rendered` disponível no componente `datatable` (e em praticamente todos os componentes JSF).

O atributo recebe um valor do tipo `boolean` e aceita o uso de [`Expression Language`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html).

Um valor negativo indica que o componente não vai ser renderizado na página.

No seu caso, você pode utilizar uma expressão parecida com:

```
<p:dataTable rendered="#{not empty responderSimuladoBean.respostas}" />
```

Existe um exemplo bem parecido disponível no [`showcase do Primefaces`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/dataTable.xhtml).